# Left/Right position a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I've a navigation bar and a `<div>` tag with `class="container-fluid"` and `id="scrollable"` with CSS property as below.

```
#scrollable {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But, When the problem is, the page is not taking the entire width on the right side.

[image: Here is the Rendering details.]

How do I make that right position value to 0, which is 72.406

Comment: Where is your html?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so, I've made the following changes to the id

```
#scrollable {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 17.5%;
}
```

and this solves the problem.

Comment: How responsive is it? Have you changed the window width to simulate different devices to see if it still works? Without code to see it ourselves we can't really help much.

Comment: Is this a question? If yes, this will be removed and you should put it in the question.

Comment: That solution worked for me when I tried. So, is that solution correct? Should that go into the question as well?

Comment: That is how I do when to position an absolute element, so I removed the question from your answer.